# AngularJS. Converting form fields to json

Tags: json, angularjs

Trying to understand how could be possible to write a function, (directive / controller) that would transform all my `form inputs` to json with current value that they have to `json`.

The json would have a format similar to that:

```
{    
    fields: [
          {field1: value1},
          {field2: value2},
          {field3, value3}
        ]    
}
```

Where to start from at least.. with no `jquery` applying?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`ng-model` does it for you. A scope variable will be created if you haven't already created it yourself

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitMyForm()">
    <input ng-model="fields.name"  />
```

```
function myController($scope){
    $scope.submitMyForm=function(){
        /* while compiling form , angular created this object*/
        var data=$scope.fields;  
        /* post to server*/
        $http.post(url, data);        
    }

}
```

If you have the object to start with in your scope angular will 2 way bind to the input, so any values that are initially set in the scope object will show up in the input

Comment: var query = [
            StartDate= $scope.StartDate.toPlanoLocalDateString(),
            EndDate= $scope.EndDate.toPlanoLocalDateString()
        ];
        var tstring = jQuery.parseJSON(query);


sir...i need to transfer these values to controller.How can i use this ...

Comment: @Sankar sould start with valid javascript.

Comment: @amit_yo same way you do any other ajax

Comment: This works fine, I have a php backend and using $_POST, how do I read the fields.name value?

Comment: @defmx default content type of `$http` is `application/json` so `$_POST` is empty. Need to use `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: @charlietfl does it work with ng repeat and with dynamic model names?

Comment: what is fields in the ng-model? we have not defined fields attribute anywhere.